# Is it possible to recover my files on a damaged portable USB hard drive?

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive

My son accidentally bump my laptop and the portable HDD fell to the floor while I'm  transferring files. How can I get my data back?

Answer (score 2):

If the drive is still working in some form - e.g. the drive is still spinning (you will be able to feel this when resting your hand on it, it will be vibrating just after you have plugged it in) - then I recommend buying a copy of [Spinrite](http://www.grc.com). If anything can still be read from the disk, Spinrite will certainly do so.

I used it a while back to recover my laptop's hard drive.

If it is not spinning at all, your only recourse is to send it to a specialist recovery service but this will cost a **lot** of money.

Comment: Also, if you are going to use spinrite, if possible remove the disk from the USB enclosure and attach it directly to the computer as Spinrite can not read the [S.M.A.R.T.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) data it uses to recover the data over a USB connection. It will still work, but not as well.

Comment: Good point Scott - though it doesn't really use SMART for much. If you listen to the author Steve Gibson, you'll realise he doesn't set much store in the SMART data except for certain limited things. Connecting direct is likely to speed things up a fair bit though.

Comment: Very true, @everyone else see [the FAQ](http://www.grc.com/sr/faq.htm) for more details about USB drives and Spinrite